# java- How to handle exception where you are unable to connect to database?

Tags: java, mysql

I was working on some program in Java and involving MySQL database. As we know, most programs need database to work with.

As I am thinking there could exceptions that could handles in the application, for example:

```
Failed to insert to db
table does not exist
etc
```

When I catch these kind of exceptions, I have the option to store this error message in a form of error code in my table under a `Error` column.

Now consider this, to establish a connection between an application and the database, I need the IP along with it's username and password before the program works.

In that case, if I were to "break" the program by giving a wrong password , or I easily terminate MySQL service while the application is running. If this happens, the application will throw some sort of database error connection since it couldn't connect to it. At the same time, I can't update the Error column of the table since no connection establish between the program and the db.

I can't seem to figure out the best way to handle this or if there is even a way to do so.

How would one handle this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

**Approach#1**

You can log these errors in a log file.
If you really want to add every error in the database, then later on you can fetch the errors by scraping the log file and insert them into the database.

**Approach#2**

You can either try to reconnect to the database & if successful, write the error to the database. If not able to connect then you can fallback to approach#1.